# the function of img_as_float and rgb2gray

Tags: python-3.x, image-processing, scikit-image

In scikit-image, there two functions, img_as_float and rgb2gray. Are they generating the same type of numerical arrays, with value of [0,1]? What are the real difference of these two functions from the underlying numpy arrays used to representing a image?

Answer (score 0):

They do different things: `img_as_float` converts an image from any type to a floating point type in [0, 1], whether it is a color image or not. For example, a (512, 512) image containing uint8 values in the range 0-255 will be converted to a (512, 512) image containing float64 values in the range 0-1. See [image data types and what they mean](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/user_guide/data_types.html) for more information.

`rgb2gray` converts an image from having 3 colors (red, green, and blue) in the final axis to one with one less axis and only intensity information, according to [this luminance formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_luminance). The reason you might be confusing this with `img_as_float` is that `rgb2gray` calls `img_as_float` on its input, before converting to grayscale. So a (512, 512, 3) uint8 image with values in 0-255 will be automatically converted to a (512, 512, 3) float64 image with values in 0-1, and *then* the luminance formula will be applied to obtain a (512, 512) image of float64 values in 0-1.